# Универсальный указатель на функцию C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Вопрос заключается в следующем: требуется создать класс, содержащий два поля: строку и указатель на функцию. Строка не требует пояснений. Проблемы вызывает **указатель**: нужно создать объекты данного класса и сделать так, чтобы каждый объект вызывал **разные** функции. При чем у функций могут **отличаться сигнатуры** (принимаемые, возвращаемые значения). Но в объектах класса поля будут одинаковыми. Поэтому требуется реализовать "*универсальный указатель*", который мог бы вызывать различные функции (присвоение адреса функции происходит в конструкторе). А также возникает вопрос по поводу вызова этих функций - каким образом в них передавать параметры, если они вызываются через метод класса? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что бы передать в функции параметры, нужно знать реальный прототип функции. А если вы его знаете, зачем вам универсальный указатель? Наделайте типизированных указателей и пользуйтесь каждым в своем месте.

Comment: Используйте `std::any`. Но вообще, когда задают такой вопрос, потом обычно выясняется, что универсальный указатель не нужен, и достаточно зашаблонировать класс, где хранится указатель.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если знаете, что именно вызываете (аргументы и тип возвращаемого значения), то в принципе, как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


using namespace std; // да, это все же С++ код, по крайней мере g++ считает его своим

typedef void * (*fany)(...);

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  fany foo = (fany)open,
    bar = (fany)perror;
  char *path = av[1] ? av[1] : (char *)"ttt.cpp";
  int fd = (ssize_t)foo(path, O_RDONLY);

  if (fd == -1) 
    exit((bar(path), 1));

  char buf[1025];
  int l;

  foo = (fany)read;
  bar = (fany)write;
  while ((l = (ssize_t)foo(fd, buf, 1024)) > 0)
    buf[l] = 0, bar(1, buf, l);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Понятно, что это пример для функций, возвращающих целый тип (не важно, указатель или число, помещающееся в один регистр).

В классы, надеюсь, сами сможете по аналогии вставить.

Comment: Минусаторы, возвысьте голос и объясните что не так с ответом? Вроде всё ОК.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, данный ответ не оценивал, но вызов функции через выражение, функциональный тип которого не совпадает с фактическим типом вызываемой функции, вызывает неопределённое поведение ([expr.call/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.call#6)). И даже если это обычно работает на практике, то нужно помнить, что [работает не всегда](https://godbolt.org/z/9PfE5h6fn).

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, но вызов функции с тремя точками запросто может отличаться от вызова функции с типизированными параметрами...

Comment: @wololo, чтобы убрать UB достаточно привести `bar` к объявленному типу перед вызовом?

Comment: Тогда лучше убрать `...` и использовать просто `void *` вместо указателя на функцию, чтобы случайно не вызвать. А ещё лучше использовать `std::any`, чтобы ловить кривые касты.

Comment: И не смотря на все комментарии это работает (по крайней мере  g++ в linux). @HolyBlackCat, что вы имеете в виду под "случайно вызвать"?  (а случайно поделить на ноль не боитесь?)

Comment: Как уже показали, с float не работает. *"случайно вызвать"* Если вы намерены всегда кастовать перед вызовом, кажется логичным защитить себя от забытого каста. Например, `dlsym()` возвращает `void *`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, с float/double, согласен (кстати, я сразу написал в ответе, что пример для функций, возвращающих **целый тип**). Для таких функций, как float/double нужен другой прототип. Что вам не нравится с возвратом `void *` (malloc, dlsym и т.п.) не понимаю

Comment: @avp Наоброт, я предлагаю вам использовать `void *` вместо `void (*)(...)`, чтобы нельзя было вызвать функцию без каста.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда в точке вызова надо будет явно прописыват кастинг (или макрос). Код грязнее будет

Comment: А, перепутал вас и StanislavVolodarskiy. Зато с кастами всегда работает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. всегда работает это про float и возврат структур? Ну, да, тогда лучше добавить макросы, а хранить только адрес. Я просто показал в ответе принцип, а не готовый API

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, это устранит UB. [expr.reinterpret.cast/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast#6): `... converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value ...`